# How to inject child router to the dialog view-model

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

In our project we have bunch of custom elements like this:

```
<entity-link id="entity.id>
```

basically it just renders a link to edit entity screen

```
<template>
    <a class="entity-link"
       route-href="route: ENTITY_EDIT; params.bind: { id: entity.id }"
            >${entity.name}
    </a>
</template>
```

the problem is that this doesn't work at all within Aurelia Dialog context.
`href` attributed is not populated at all.

I tried to investigate the issue, I injected the router directly to dialog's view-model

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
@inject(DialogController, Router)
export default class RecordDetailsDialog {
constructor(dialogController:DialogController, router:Router) {
        this.controller = dialogController;
        this.router = router;     /// WRONG INSTANCE!!!
    }
}
```

and figured out the wrong instance of Router is being injected. 
Main router (AppRouter) doesn't define ENTITY_EDIT route, it's added dynamically in child route configureRoute function.

I don't understand why the injected router is the main one instead of the one passed to the view which initiate dialog opening.

Any advice please

Answer (score 0):

so after 2 hours of reading aurelia's source code I found out that DialogService instance is created within the root DI container which is associated with the root Router which is unaware about children routes. 
I worked around our problem by registering DialogService instance manually within Child view-model container

```
  import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
  import {CompositionEngine} from 'aurelia-templating';
  import {DialogService} from 'aurelia-dialog';

  export class Main {

  constructor(container:Container, compositionEngine:CompositionEngine){
    container.registerInstance(DialogService, new DialogService(container,   compositionEngine))`
  }
     ...
  }
```

but it feels hacky, still wondering if there is a more clean way to solve the problem.